# Can instantiate a class but cant use it

Tags: c#

I have two classes and I've been able to instantiate one class in the other, but when ever I try to use the instantiated class, I get an error. I can't use the instantiated class and VS even reports that instantiated class doesn't exist. Please why is that?

```
public class GradeBook
{
    public GradeBook()
    {
        gradesList = new List<float>();
    }

    public void AddGrades(float grades)
    {
        gradesList.Add(grades);  
    }

     List<float> gradesList;

    public List<float> GradesList
    {
        get
        {
            return gradesList;
        }

        set
        {
            gradesList = value;
        }
    }
}




public class GradeStatistics
{

    GradeBook aveg = new GradeBook();

//This is where the error occurs

    aveg.GradesList; 
}
```

Comment: This line `aveg.GradesList;` is invalid. Should be something like `var myGradeList = aveg.GradesList;`

Comment: Your code is in the body of the class instead of the body of a method or property.

Comment: @mparnisari That also wouldn't comply because it's not in a method body.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally if you have an error always post the details of that error. The same goes for if you have a run time Exception.

Comment: @juharr: but even in a method or property it would be invalid without assigning `aveg.GradesList` to a variable or doing something else with it.

Comment: @mparnisari I think with the absence of a method as mentioned as mentioned above didn't make the code valid and still produced an error.

Comment: @juharr and Tim, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class cannot contain code, unless it is in a method, property, etc. Your code which creates the instance and accesses its property, is not. Create a new method in your class which contains your code. Furthermore: you should do something with the value from the property:

```
public class GradeStatistics
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        GradeBook aveg = new GradeBook();
        var result = aveg.GradesList; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile either, `GradesList` is not a method but a property, you have to do something with it if you access the getter. **Edit** Now it does compile

Comment: @AlexTurcan: without `var result =` you would get _"Only assignment, call, increment, decrements, await expression and new object expressions can be used as a statement"_

Answer (score 0):

First
You could use just the property for the List object and your method to 
add items will be obsolete since `List` has an own method to add items.

```
public class GradeBook
{

    // Property of type List (short version)
    public List<float> GradesList {get; set;}

    public GradeBook()
    {
        GradesList = new List<float>();
    }

}
```

as already mentioned in the comments you need to use the `GradeBook` object inside the constructor or a method like

```
public class GradeStatistics
{
    // constructor
    public GradeStatistics()
    {
        GradeBook aveg = new GradeBook();

        //This will stop the error to occur
        //
        aveg.GradesList.Add(0.65f); 
    }
}
```

or you create also a property in the new class

```
public class GradeStatistics
{

    public GradeBook aveg {get; set;}

    // constructor
    public GradeStatistics()
    {
        // from now on you can use it also in methods
        aveg = new GradeBook();

    }

    public void clearForeignList()
    {
         this.aveg.GradesList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you code once again and look @martin-mulder answer. Here's a perfectly wokring code:

```
public class GradeBook
    {
        public GradeBook()
        {
            gradesList = new List<float>();
        }

        public void AddGrades(float grades)
        {
            gradesList.Add(grades);
        }

        List<float> gradesList;

        public List<float> GradesList
        {
            get
            {
                return gradesList;
            }

            set
            {
                gradesList = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class GradeStatistics
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            GradeBook aveg = new GradeBook();
           var x = aveg.GradesList;
        }
}
```